# Algorithm for movie recomendations

Tags: java, web-services, algorithm

I'm want to understand how recommendations website work, so i was wondering if any of you guys could point me in the right direction in terms of movie recommendations

What algorithms are out there at the moment. What would be the main basis of these algorithms, how would i ensure that these algorithms are as accurate as possible? What type of technology would be needed to implement one of these into a website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scoring / rating engines - advice and examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977390/scoring-rating-engines-advice-and-examples)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124590/recommendation-system-for-a-book-store-application

Comment: In spite of your use of the word *Algorithm* in the title of this question, the relevance to programming is tenuous. Don't be surprised if the question is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about singular value decomposition. It is used to find clusters in high-dimensional spaces. 
See 
http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/svd.html

Comment: This is a cool and efficient recomendation system, i may research this one some more, good share